# Clipping Raster through a shapefile using Python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, shapefile, clip

I've been trying to clip a raster file with a corresponding shape file using gdal Warp. However, I am encountering an error as follows:

<osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x7f30542b86c0> >

```
from osgeo import gdal

rasin = "location of raster file.tif"
output = "destination of clipped raster file.tif"
shpin = "location of shapefile.shp"

gdal.Warp(output, rasin, cutlineDSName = shpin, format="GTiff", cropToCutline = True)
```

Comment: This is not an error. gdal.Warp returns a gdal Dataset object.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Thank you for the answer, but the output which I get contains blank image. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Could you upload the clipping shape and the raster? Also this sort of questions is really good for https://gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

`rasterio` will be a good choice.

```
import fiona
import rasterio
import rasterio.mask

src_raster_path = r'LC09_L2SP_007025_20220703_20220705_02_T1_SR_B2.TIF'

shp_file_path = "water_polygons.shp"

output_raster_path = src_raster_path[:-3] + 'water_masked.tif'

with fiona.open(shp_file_path, "r") as shapefile:
    shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]

with rasterio.open(src_raster_path) as src:

    out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, shapes, crop=True)
    out_meta = src.meta

out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                 "height": out_image.shape[1],
                 "width": out_image.shape[2],
                 "transform": out_transform})


with rasterio.open(output_raster_path, "w", **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(out_image)
```

Comment: He asks for a solution using gdal.Warp